# Can We deploy Microsoft bot Application in IIS without Azure?

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

Is it possible to deploy Microsoft bot Application in IIS without Azure.

We have created a sample bot Application and running fine with the Emulator in local environment.

We would like to move the application to the Production and don't have Azure account and details.

Can we deploy bot application in the IIS in Windows server 2012 R2 as how we deploy Webservices or WCF Services ? Is it Possible without Azure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using Azure Bot Service (i.e. Azure Functions), you can host your bot anywhere.  You simply need to provide the endpoint for your bot during [registration](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. And the answer is: Sure you can! But the bad new is, that you have to publish in a valid HTTPS. So I think in this case is more simple publish on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i you use azure you can use you application anywhere and make sure credentials while configuring bot.

Dont forget to configure webhooks or endpoint url