# Can We deploy Microsoft bot Application in IIS for hosting without Azure?

Tags: iis-7.5, bots, botframework

Is it possible to deploy Microsoft bot Application in IIS without Azure.

We have created a sample bot Application and running fine with the Emulator in local environment.

We would like to move the application to the Production and don't have Azure account and details.

Can we deploy bot application in the IIS in Windows server 2012 R2 as how we deploy Webservices or WCF Services ? Is it Possible without to host in IIS without Azure ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can We deploy Microsoft bot Application in IIS without Azure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480297/can-we-deploy-microsoft-bot-application-in-iis-without-azure)

Answer (score 7):

Of course it is possible. You just need to deploy your bot code to your IIS server, and copy-paste the URL of your API endpoint into the bot settings on dev.botframework.com.

For example, the URL could look like this:

```
https://yourserver.com/api/messages
```

One caveat is that it must use HTTPS, so you may need to take care of your own SSL certificate.

On the other hand, an Azure account is free and according to my experience, can easily handle thousands of users daily within the free quota.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have added the HTTPs and hosted in IIS.

Comment: Now How to use the same service from the Emulator

Comment: There shouldn't be any changes necessary for the emulator - it uses localhost:9000/api/messages, another server