# How to Deploy Microsoft Bot in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, bots, botframework

I'm trying to deploy my Bot in IIS instead of Azure and use the same endpoint during the bot registration. I tried mocking Steps from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-your-asp-net-mvc-5-app-to-iis-8/).

Can anyone suggest me if this is the right way to host bot in IIS. Now i'm getting below error following the steps from the link.

```
 The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed: could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls secure channel
```

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482022/can-we-deploy-microsoft-bot-application-in-iis-for-hosting-without-azure