# Bot Framework without Azure possible?

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

If i'm building a bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework, do i need to deploy my bot to Azure in order to register my bot [HERE](https://dev.botframework.com/) in order to configure the channels for the bot? 
Or can i simply deploy my bot to a normal (for example) IIS Server?

I couldnt find any information on this toppic and i dont want to use Azure.

Comment: Are u looking for running the bot in a development environment or would you like make your bot available to others and not using Azure for that?

Comment: I would like to have my bot available to others (it should be an E-Mail-Bot) and not use Azure.

Comment: Did you ever find a replacement for Azure Bot Service? :(

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to run your bot on IIS or in any other hosting service (including cloud hostings besides Azure) as explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/693). You will have to make sure that your bot has an internet-accessible endpoint and a valid HTTPS cert.

Regarding the requirements for the HTTPS cert, I'm copying the info for this [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1328) for your reference:

> The Bot Framework requires that the x.509v3 certificate exposed by
>   your endpoint be current and valid. Most of the checks for "current
>   and valid" are standard checks for server certs: the CN must match the
>   hostname, it must not be expired, it must not be listed in a CRL, it
>   must have the correct set of EKUs, etc.
>
> Most importantly, your cert must chain to a root certificate authority
>   trusted by Microsoft. The latest list of these CAs is available [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants-v-2016-april.aspx).

Also, you can register your bot and even enable the channels without deploying to Azure or any other hosting. You can temporarily use [ngrok to create a secure tunnel to your localhost environment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2016/07/29/ms-bot-framework-ngrok/) and test the bot in your email channel before exposing it to other users. BTW, you don't need to Publish your  bot in the BotFramework portal, just register it. Publishing is just for those bots that would like to appear in the [Bot Directory](https://bots.botframework.com/).

Comment: edit: With IIS i dont mean some cloud service, i mean a normal Webserver.

Comment: Yes, I know what IIS is :) but I wanted to be generic in the answer to address your specific request (IIS) and also potential other similar type of questions

Comment: But now it seems the only way for registering a bot is by creating an Azure service.

Comment: @Poulad this is true however I believe that you don't have to host it with azure if you create a Bot Channels Registration Bot and host it else where. It is also free to send messages with Standard channels: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/bot-service/

Comment: It's ok. Botframework does not need to be hosted on azure, but you need to configure bot channel registration in azure. There's no getting away from it. Is correct?

Comment: I want to add my own hosted bot to skype group chat, can I do it without azure ?

Answer (score 6):

You need an account at Azure, but you don't need to host your bot directly at Azure. There are three options when you login to Azure dashboard: Web App Bot, Functions Bot and the Bot Channels Registration. Choose the Bot Channels Registration and type your bot's https URL (where you deployed it) there in settings.

Or if you want to debug your bot directly from the messenger (not emulator) you can download ngrok, then type in command line

```
ngrok.exe http <your port> -host-header="localhost:<your port>
```

then enter the ngrok proxy URL (without port) to Bot Channels Registration settings.
Within several hours that temporary address will forward to your localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the developing a bot is totally possible without using Azure Cloud portal.

- You just need bot builder SDK for node.js or C#.
- A code editor like VSCode
- Testing on the bot emulator provided by Microsoft

  But for publishing the bot on channels or web apps you will have to register the Bot with Azure bot service.
  Check more here: https://thewebspark.com/2018/04/15/is-microsoft-bot-framework-without-azure-possible/

Comment: Hi Sarhk , Do we have any other free channel to register the Bot  apart from Azure ot service

Answer (score 2):

Yes your bot is like an API that is consumed by a chat frontend like Facebook Messenger, Skype etc. Check out this medium blog explaining how to host on Heroku https://medium.com/@chinnatiptaemkaeo/create-fb-bot-with-heroku-nodejs-microsoft-bot-framework-687bd2893238

Answer (score 2):

It is totally possible.

I ran it 2 ways.
1st - restify service in a docker container - run locally with and ngrok and on AWS

```
// Create HTTP server.
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\n${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});

async function main(req: WebRequest, context: TurnContext) {
    logger.json("Request ->", req.body);
    try {
        for (const bot of allBots) {
            await bot.run(context);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error("Error processing request[server.ts]");
        logger.error(error);
    }
}
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post("/api/messages", (req: WebRequest, res: WebResponse) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context: TurnContext) => {
        await main(req, context);
    });
});
```

2nd - run on AWS Lambda with Serverless framework. Here is the adapter.

```
export function lambda(bots: ActivityHandler[]) {
    const handler: Handler = async (event: any, _: Context, callback: Callback) => {
        logger.json("Event to bot framework: ", event);
        const reqWrapper: WebRequest = {
            body: event.body,
            headers: event.headers,
            method: event.method,
            query: event.query,
            on: (_1: string, ..._2: any[]): any => {
                // it needs to be empty
            },
        };
        let statusCode: number;
        const resWrapper: WebResponse = {
            status: (code: number) => {
                statusCode = code;
            },
            send: (body) => {
                callback(null, {statusCode, body});
            },
            end: () => {
                callback(null, { statusCode });
            },
        };

        const adapter = await getAdapter();

        adapter.processActivity(reqWrapper, resWrapper, async (context: TurnContext) => {
            await main(context, bots);
        });
    };
    return handler;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to explain this a bit more, especially the configuration part on the webchat