# Can I use self signed certificate for deploying microsoft bot in Testing environment

Tags: certificate, botframework

Is it possible to use self signed certificate and use it as a binding on a website and deploy microsoft bot code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 3):

Not currently possible. See more information here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/786