# can we create a custom chat page for bot application?

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

I am building a bot with the Microsoft bot framework. I don't want to use bot(other than webchat) emulator and don't want to use Azure also.I want to host my bot in local IIS only. Instead of using bot emulator I want to create my own custom chat page for chat with bot. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible) but didn't get any idea. Is there any way to do so?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can host your bot into your local IIS if you have valid SSL certificate. 
Your endpoint must be https.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: Into your botframework dashboard : http://prntscr.com/f95v5k. 
Creating your web site and other stuff is another thing to discuss.

Comment: @BobSwager I have hosted it in the local IIS of my VM, and there is no internet connection. So inside that VM how can i make conversation with bot without bot emulator?

Comment: How is even possible to connect without internet connection ? :)

Comment: ok let us say we have internet connection, then can we make the conversation with bot without bot emulator, like if i want to use a web page instead of bot emulator....?

Comment: If you've internet connection you can use ngrok to make your local address public. Then, for endpoint use generated address from ngrok. 
At the end, send web chat to your testers.

Comment: I'll check it. Thank you :)

Comment: I added last comment as an answer to this thread. Please mark it. :) 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've internet connection you can use ngrok to make your local address public. Then, for endpoint use generated address from ngrok. At the end, send web chat to your testers.