# how to publish bot framework c# code to windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I need to publish bot framework c# code to windows server 2012 r2 but what do I set "Server" , "Site name" , and Destination URL to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-visual-studio

Comment: i need to publish in windows server 2012 r2 not at azure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying a bot to IIS is the same as deploying any website.

There's a nice walkthrough of installing **Web Deploy** on Windows Server 2012 R2 here: http://www.developerhandbook.com/visual-studio/publish-website-to-iis-using-web-deploy/ and another one here: http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012/

Once **Web Deploy** is installed and configured, you can import the deployment profile into visual studio and the server, sitename and destination url will be populated correctly.

```
Server=YourServerName
SiteName=YourBotWebSiteName
DestinationUrl=WebDeploymentUrl
```

Comment: showing error as could not connect to the remote computer(severname). Make sure that the remote computer is correct and that you are able to connect to the computer. Error Destination invalid

Comment: Is Web Deploy installed on the Windows Server?  ...another option is to just manually deploy.  You can create a website in IIS on the server, and manually copy the files there.

Comment: wep deploy is installed.. if i manually copy the files there in wwwroot, create a website in iis and assign physical path also it is showing error as 500 internal sever error

Comment: Have you installed the corresponding version of .net on the server?

Comment: Please open the bot project's properties, and ensure that "Target framework:" version of .net is installed on the server.  4.0 is not a high enough version