# How to trouble shoot "Refresh access token failed with status code: 401 " in bot on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, windows-server-2012-r2

I have deployed my bot on a remote windows server 2012r2 and when i try to connect with it using emulator, it gives me the error **Refresh access token failed with status code: 401**

I have followed all the steps discussed here and used a web deploy method to deploy. [how to publish bot framework c-sharp code to windows server 2012r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234788/how-to-publish-bot-framework-c-sharp-code-to-windows-server-2012-r2)

Comment: 401 indicates an authentication failure. Have you got a) the bot Id and password conrrectly configured on the server and emulator b) configured ngrok and c) checked you can access the bot via HTTP?

Comment: And also make sure you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible

Comment: @startd yes, it was because of incorrect passwords. Note: do not copy passwords directly from emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it was because of incorrect password. I was copying it directly from the emulator. So yes, after putting correct ID and Password it went away.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ehsan! Seems you've found answer of your question. If you are sure that this is the correct answer then don't hesitate to mark it as answered to help others find this solution quickly. P.S. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/