# Is it possible to host my Microsoft Bot locally in our network and still use facebook/slack as a connector?

Tags: .net, azure, bots, botframework

We have made an bot using Microsoft Bot Framework(With C#).I want it to be installed at the server side of our application and have facebook as well as slack as connector.We do not want the bot to be available outside the network as it will query the database present in the same machine.I am not sure whether this is possible or not even after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Please tell me if this is achievable.

Comment: so you don't want the bot to be outside the network (a.k.a. available from internet) but you want to have user talking to the bot via facebook/slack? How that would work if your bot is not exposed internet?

Comment: You need to somehow route traffic from facebook/slack to the bot.  So the bot needs to be externally accessible.

Comment: @ Ezequiel Jadib @CtrlDot Lets assume that the bot would be externally accessible.Can It be hosted on any server instead of hosting it in azure  because my database will be present in the same server only

Comment: @DChamp of course.  Host is wherever you would like and configure it in the bot dev center.

Comment: Exactly and follow what is explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible