# Deploy Bot in local IIS and include it in custom chat in a webpage

Tags: html, .net, iis, visual-studio-2015, botframework

Is it possible to deploy bot in local IIS and then link it to a custom chat application which we create? if possible, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 4):

You can deploy it in IIS, I did so successfully. I published it to a folder (using the file system method in VS 2015) and then created a new Application in IIS whose /root folder was the location of the published bot.

Make sure that you enable POST requests for the site after you publish it.

[image: Request Filtering]

[image: HTTP Verb Settings]

Also make sure you have a SSL certificate.