# My microsoft bot framework does not work in digital ocean

Tags: botframework, digital-ocean

I did deploy my microsoft bot framework app to digital ocean. It is working when you make request from browser. But from console of microsoft bot framework I can not send message from test messenger. I made all of requirements: added appid and password, set up nginx and proxy. What i had to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bot hosted on Digitalocean, that is registered on the MS Botframework and can be accessed by Skype. So it definitely is possible.

Your endpoint at Digitalocean should be SSL (!) and the registered URL look like this:

https://www.yourregistereddomain.com/api/messages

Answer (score 1):

The Bot Framework works with bots deployed on any cloud hosting service, as long as you have an internet-accessible endpoint and a **valid HTTPS cert**.

**The Bot Framework requires that the x.509v3 certificate exposed by your endpoint be current and valid**. Most of the checks for "current and valid" are standard checks for server certs: the CN must match the hostname, it must not be expired, it must not be listed in a CRL, it must have the correct set of EKUs, etc.

Most importantly, your cert must chain to a root certificate authority trusted by Microsoft. The latest list of these CAs is available here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants-v-2016-april.aspx

For more information on deploying your bot, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-overview

Relates to:

- [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)
- [Deploy Bot in local IIS and incle it in custom chat in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558760/deploy-bot-in-local-iis-and-incle-it-in-custom-chat-in-a-webpage/44571251#44571251)