# iis hosting Microsoft Bot

Tags: iis, frameworks, bots, botframework

I can get the emulator to work but not the webchat or any other channel. I do have a valid ssl. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any advice would be much appreciated.

I have done what this answer says but it still does not work.

[Deploy Bot in local IIS and incle it in custom chat in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558760/deploy-bot-in-local-iis-and-incle-it-in-custom-chat-in-a-webpage#)

**Update errors**
Here is the error from the server:

BF-DirectLine+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.2++https://botframework.com/ua) - 405 0 1 35

Here is an error from the dev tools in chrome:
500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is an error from botframework:

There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code MethodNotAllowed

Comment: What happens? Post an error code or something for us to help you.

Comment: Here is the error from the server:
BF-DirectLine+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.2++https://botframework.com/ua) - 405 0 1 35

Here is an error from the dev tools in chrome:
500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is an error from botframework:
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code MethodNotAllowed