# Deploying MS Bot Framework using AWS

Tags: node.js, facebook, amazon-web-services, lambda, botframework

I currently have a Facebook Messenger bot that is built using the MS Bot Framework and I searched for ways on how to deploy it using AWS.

I found results in google that using [Lambda](https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/run-facebook-messenger-chat-bot-on-aws-lambda-2fa800a67d76) will work but when I try testing my bot it will log that it is Forbidden.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible

Comment: Here I show you how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible/60537664#60537664

Answer (score 1):

The Bot Framework works with bots deployed on any cloud hosting service, as long as you have an internet-accessible endpoint and a valid SSL certificate.
The Bot Framework requires that the x.509v3 certificate exposed by your endpoint be current and valid. Most of the checks for "current and valid" are standard checks for server SSL certificates: the Certificate Name must match the hostname, it must not be expired, it must not be listed in a CRL, it must have the correct set of EKUs, etc.
Most importantly, your SSL certificate must chain to a root certificate authority trusted by Microsoft. The latest list of these CAs is available here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants-v-2016-april.aspx