# How to register and add a slack channel for bot that is deployed in local IIS

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a created a bot that is interacted with database (sql server) to get the data. I have deployed/publish the bot in local IIS and its working fine with the emulator. Now I want to register the bot and add it to the Slack channel. I am using Windows Server 2012 for development.

I have gone through many articles but did not find any information.

Kindly help me on this?

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try to activate Slack channel on botframework portal (and follow the process indicated there)?

Comment: No, I did not try it yet. I was not sure if we can add slack channel when bot is configured locally. Is it possible? If yes then will try and follow the process.

Comment: Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible/40889296 and other search, it should be possible as long as your deployed bot is accessible from the Internet and you have a valid https certificate so you may give it a try