# How to host Microsoft Bot on premise in IIS manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot I want to host on premise and I've hosted the bot on a domain with a valid SSL cert via letsencrypt. The cert bound to the domain the bot is hosted on is by IdenTrust (DST Root CA X3) which is a participant of the Microsoft root certification program.

The DB the bot is connected to is the local database in the server. However, the domain the bot is hosted on is accessible via web call. The db can also be accessed via another application hosted under the same site the bot is hosted on.

However, I can't access the bot and I keep getting the error below:
[There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError]

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Comment: Internal Server Error generally means there is an issue in the bot code.  Are you 100% certain that the bot is not being reached?  Can you navigate to the Messaging Endpoint in a browser?  It should return: 'The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." if hosted in IIS.

Comment: @EricDahlvang hey man, yes the endpoint is returning the message string u said!

Comment: LetsEncrypt does not appear to be one of Microsoft's Trusted Root Certificate Program Participants: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants.aspx

Comment: Hey @EricDahlvang, turns out it was a port exposure issue and not the SSL cert itself! Thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Webchat client talks to Azure MS bot through Directline API which is hosted in Azure-cloud. You need to find a way to talk to local MS bot through DirectLine API. 
Sadly, I don't think if there is any local(on premise) version of DirectLine API.