# how to directly talk to botbuilder?

Tags: botframework

For a few days, I have been trying to make a bot using Microsoft BotBuilder.

I want to use the bot within an app locally.

1. I don't want to deploy it to azure or other servers.
2. I want to talk to it just like using emulator by  resifting it, but i will not use emulator?

So far, I tried the following.

1. defined an endpoint using "express".
2. tried to call the API, but it did not invoke the first dialog, did not show any error.

So, in this case, what I need to do? 
what is the way to use a bot within an app while still developing it?

Could anyone point out what should i do?

Comment: Usually the emulator is using while developing. Why you don't want to use it?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I want to know if we can keep it local and can use like that without deploying or using emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Comment: This is really more than one question, I'm not sure what you mean by not wanting to deploy to "azure or other servers".  Where will you host your bot, or the app that contains your bot? Can you also please post the code you are using to call the API?