# How can i host Microsoft Bot framework on premise?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am planning to implement Microsoft Bot framework, using Qna and LUIS, but my organization policy restricts me from using hosting my KB outside premice, Can i host Microsoft Bot framework in house?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't host Microsoft Bot Framework on your premises right at the moment. But what you can do is consuming their APIs inside your application.

Please refer this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts)

Thanks

Comment: The people who are down voting my answer please make sure to add the reason, then even I can learn something.