# How to embed Webchat control in website to connect to Microsoft bot service without registering bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I am just trying my hands on Microsoft Bot Service. I created a default Bot service using the template in Visual studio 2017. And I hosted the service in IIS and tested it via Emulator. It is working.

Now, I would like to create my own client for the BOT service i.e  my own website (and not use Emulator) where I want to have a WebChat control embedded within it and connect to the Bot Service. 
I read few articles on embedding WebChat within website but there is step to register the bot.  Is it mandatory to register your bot before you use it within your website?

Regards,
NAK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Comment: @NicolasR My question is more on creating a client(website) and not use emulator. I think the link what you suggested is more of hosting the BotService right?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want a short answer to "Is it mandatory to register your bot before you use it within your website?", the answer is yes

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I tried to mark as duplicate but was unable to do so since the answer (on the other question) hadn't been accepted yet. This is a flaw in the Stack Overflow design. I don't want to post duplicate answers either.