# Bot created using "Bot Channel Registration" not working

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating "Bot" using "Microsoft Bot Framework" NodeJs platform.

Below are the steps which I've followed

1) Created bot (NodeJs) & hosted it on SSL certified server (AWS)

2) Registered bot "Bot Channel Registration" on azure ( Configured AppId & Password in app.js)

3) Enabled the bot for skype for business using channel configuration settings

4) Working fine in "**Test in webchat**"

But when i'm trying same using skype for business account its giving me 
"**Error happened in Skype for Business service when reaching bot service.**"

I tried to check logs on portal.azure.com there its showing me

**There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout**

Can you please guide me on same why i'm facing this issue.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please see this answer and see if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible

Comment: while developing referred that , but still its not working. works sometimes. but most of the time its gives   "Error happened in Skype for Business service when reaching bot service."  this error

Comment: @JasonSowers  Even its working fine for skype but not working  for "**skype for business**"

Comment: is it because of custom port i.e **3978** which i'm using for "Endpoint Url"

Comment: It could be but doubtful, I generally do not include ports in my messaging endpoints.  Unfortunately, we get this all too often where it will work on many other channels but not in teams.  I would try using [this guide](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) to debug locally with ngrok and see if you can get more information.  I also added the ms teams tag hoping someone from that team can help.There is also [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview) that may help as well if you have not seen it

Comment: @JasonSowers, we are using default SSL port for "endpoint URL" i.e 443. But still its not working for "**skype for business**". my query is  the SSL certificate which we are using is from normal ssl from GoDaddy.com. Bot requires same "SSL" or some other like Microsoft's "SSL" certified server ??

Comment: Since this is working on other channels it is unlikely your certificate is the problem.   Depending on the setup of your [admin controls](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/New-admin-controls-for-apps-in-Teams/ba-p/78975) you may have to [sideload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload) your bot