# MS BOT Service Data Flow

Tags: botframework

If we develop a bot using BOT SDK (.NET) what will be data flow. In other words which data will be going to Azure cloud and which data will remain in our local machine. If we are not going to use any channel subscription like Skype will it be necessary to host the bot in Azure cloud.
Note: We are using only LUIS service as of now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Comment: You can host a Skype bot locally.  You just need to have an internet accessible https endpoint (with some other rules, provided in the link shared by Jason).  You can use a custom state client, and store conversation state on your own server too.  Messages pass through the bot connector services, to communicate with your bot and the channels.

Comment: @Eric Dahlvang  so if we don't use any channel registration then will our conversations go through the cloud or will it be stored in local machine only

Comment: How would you not use any channel registration?  Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline but there are many limitations.  The Emulator has a built in directline server https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator but again, there are many limitations.

Comment: @Eric Dahlvang  can you explain me the flow of conversation data when using directline API. We don' t want our conversation data to be stored in any other cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some diagrams in this doc that might help illustrate the flow of messages between the connector services and direct line clients: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication

The DirectLine has a cache of messages for connectivity reasons, but it is not a permanent message store.  Messages are encrypted while at rest, and purged after some time (I believe it is 24 hours).  Dialogs and state information (ConversationData, PrivateConversationData and UserData) can be persisted using your own data store: see https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure