# How to debug remote microsoft bot?

Tags: chatbot

I have a bot that I want to host in my own webspace vs Azure.

It works fine locally and when I deploy on Azure.  When I publish it to my own site and update the endpoint in Azure ... it won't work.  When I do 'test in web' on Azure it uses the version there instead of the version I deployed which is very irritating.  I have no idea what is going on as I don't believe the emulator works with remote sites.

So I'm asking the community - is there a known way I can debug the remote code - my host is Brinkster.com and I have my SSL cert working and .NET 4.6 installed.

I referenced this article before posting: [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Thanks,

-Mike