# How to deploy Microsoft Bot Framework app in Azure Virtual machine?

Tags: azure, deployment, botframework, azure-virtual-machine

How to deploy Microsoft chatbot service in Azure Virtual machine instead of using App service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot Framework without Azure possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll want to set up your azure virtual machine as normal. Once this is done install node and npm via the console, clone your bot repository, and then run `npm install`.

After this you can run your bot as normal from the command line, just make sure to open up the port your bot is running on, then set up a bot registration channel pointed at `http:<virtualmachinepublicip>:<port>/api/messages`

Comment: Thanks Mark B for your answer,  Is there anyway possible without enabling public IP in Azure VM?

Comment: If that is a required part of this setup, could you please add it to your question?