# Publishing a Microsoft Bot

Tags: c#, botframework, messenger

I'm trying to deploy a test bot on messenger however, when it comes to the endpoint url I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm not completely clued up on how the hosting works.

I've got it linked to my Facebook page but I get no response and I'm told no endpoint detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look to the [Deploy a bot to the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-overview) documentation section.

Also, make sure to review the topic around how to [Connect a bot to Facebook Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-facebook) to ensure all the steps are being done correctly.

Comment: So that's what i'm missing, the bot living on a cloud or server ?

Comment: The quicker and easier is to deploy the bot to Azure. You can host the bot on your own server per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480297/can-we-deploy-microsoft-bot-application-in-iis-without-azure); however, it's more complex.

Comment: Greetings, The End point URL provided by Luis, Can this be used as the end point when registering a bot or does it have to be pushed up to a server and that used as the end point url ?

Comment: No, the URL that LUIS is giving you if in case you want to query LUIS directly. When registering a bot you need to provide the URL of where your bot will be hosted.